# Wildcards using LTRIM in SQL Lite

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, substring

I'm trying to use LTRIM to split the following field 'hours' - trimming off the characters from the left up to and including the pipe | symbol.

```
Monday|11:00-18:00
```

to result in

```
11:00-18:00
```

I would have thought the following code is correct

```
LTRIM(hours, '%|')
```

But it just isn't working.  The query runs but the above statement has no affect. Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Richard

Comment: What made you think `ltrim()` uses wildcards? [The documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ltrim) doesn't say it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `instr()` to compute the position of the pipe character in the string, and `substr()` to select everything after that position:

```
substr(col, instr(col, '|') + 1) as newcol
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=31707afdd6b9088e7fdfa479de8df17f)**:

```
with t as (select 'Monday|11:00-18:00' col)
select substr(col, instr(col, '|') + 1) as newcol from t
```

```
| newcol      |
| :---------- |
| 11:00-18:00 |
```